# Relative path Not works

Tags: java

I have a folder structure like:

```
myDir
  resources
    myConfig.cfg

  in
    infile.txt  

  myProgram.jar -->runnable jar file
```

I tried to use the relative path `./in/infile.txt`
I'm mentioning these relative paths from myConfig.cfg.

In code, i use like,

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("./resources/myConfig.cfg"));
```

What is the error ?
The same worked for another jar and the same path.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: yes. As usual FileNotFoundException. I tried with different relative paths like ./, .../..,../,etc. The ./in/infile.txt perfectly works for another process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myConfig.cfg"));
```

Actually when compiled resource folder is not used but all the resource files are moved under "classes" dir

Comment: I wish to keep the config files out of the jar.. so that i can edit it when needed. How can i do that?

Comment: Actually, I have problem in accessing the infile.txt. Config file is reading fine. With the code I use, I can edit it even after comiling and creating jar. (Pl correct me, if using config file out, is bad idea).

Comment: it's fine to use external file but to get the new values you have to either restart app or add kind of refreshing the configs

Comment: yes. restarting it everytime. But, i have issue reading the infile.txt's path.. Am I wrong with the relative path used for that?